# window.open crashes windows 8 phone phonegap app

Tags: windows-phone-8, cordova, phonegap-build

In my windows phone 8 cordova application, I make a call to window.open() as follows:

```
window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

As anyone would expect, this crashes the application. Is there any way I can ask Windows Phone 8 to stop being such a big bully. Android and iOS think this code is all right.

Comment: Why would you expect that to crash the application? It should work fine depending on the url you pass to it (the InAppBrowser should actually hijack it if it is enabled). Assuming you're testing this on the SDK's emulator, are you seeing anything weird in the debug console (such as System.UriFormatException)?

Comment: I don't have the SDK. I don't have Windows 8, so Microsoft won't let me install it. This is actually feedback I'm getting from trying to submit the app to the Windows Phone Store. It should work fine, shouldn't it?